# Why can't VS2008 place an exception helper popup onto a secondary monitor?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, multiple-monitors

I've recently acquired a second monitor and now run VS2008 SP1 maximized on my secondary (and bigger) monitor. This theoretically has the benefit of opening the application under development on the primary monitor, where -- as it seems to me -- all newly started applications go. So far, so good. The problem though is now, that the exception helper popup is **not** opened on the secondary monitor. Even worse, it is **only** shown when the Studio window is far enough on the primary monitor! If I drag the studio with an opened exception helper from the primary to the secondary monitor, the helper is dragged with the window until it hits the border between the two monitors, where it suddenly **disappears**.

Has somebody experienced this too? Is there any workaround? Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS isn't multi monitor aware.  I believe they're looking at improving the multimonitor experience in the next version.

Comment: "not aware" is quite the under statement :-) I'd call that actively hostile

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go THAT far.  There were rumblings about multimonitor support in VS Next and some calls out for what we'd like to see a few months ago on the msdn blogs.  I sent a bunch of suggestions; we'll have to see what happens.  But ANY program not multimonitor aware has these kinds of issues

Comment: I have to grant them "good intentions". For example I can see the reasoning behind restoring the Studio's WindowState from Minimized to Normal at the end of the debugging session. But why does it have to steal the focus from the other window I'm working in?

Answer (score 1):

I run dual 22" widescreens and have the same issue, if you have one monitor that is larger or mor commonly used the ONLY thing that I know that will truly work is to make the larger desired monitor the primary.  It isn't elegant, and might not even be appropriate for you, but that is all I have been able to do.